# Angular Universal build hangs on prerendering page with API request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-universal

I'm working on a small web app based on the [angular universal starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) and the [pokeapi](https://pokeapi.co/). Since a lot of the data that I want to show doesn't actually change, I want to use pre-rendered pages to reduce the number of requests made to the API and to improve performance. For my example I have put a list of pokemons on the home page of my app which I retrieve from the API.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    pokemon$: ReplaySubject<ResourceList> = new ReplaySubject<ResourceList>();

    constructor(private pokedexService: PokedexService, private state: TransferState) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.state.hasKey(STATE_KEY_POKEMON)) {
            this.pokemon$.next(this.state.get(STATE_KEY_POKEMON, {} as ResourceList));
        }
        else {
            this.pokedexService.getResourceByCategory(ResourceCategory.POKEMON)
                .subscribe((resourceList: ResourceList) => {
                    this.pokemon$.next(resourceList);
                    this.state.set(STATE_KEY_POKEMON, resourceList.results);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when I have the client render the page. However, when I attempt to pre-render the app, the build process hangs. Since I'm running a local instance of the API, I can see that a request was made and it returned with a 200 status. The build log looks like this:

```
npm run build:prerender

> ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 build:prerender C:\Users\thijs\Development\pokedex universal\angular-universal-pokedex
> npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && npm run generate:prerender


> ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles C:\Users\thijs\Development\pokedex universal\angular-universal-pokedex
> ng build --prod && ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production


Date: 2018-09-22T16:47:41.687Z
Hash: c49708f1ccb7e73e327a
Time: 8181ms
chunk {0} runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.c174e4dc122f769bd68b.js (polyfills) 64.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.19481e4ceb7a5808fe78.js (main) 312 kB [initial] [rendered]

Date: 2018-09-22T16:47:50.816Z
Hash: ee7e30e1f9c277bb5cbf
Time: 5739ms
chunk {main} main.js (main) 38.2 kB [entry] [rendered]

> ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 compile:server C:\Users\thijs\Development\pokedex universal\angular-universal-pokedex
> tsc -p server.tsconfig.json


> ng-universal-demo@0.0.0 generate:prerender C:\Users\thijs\Development\pokedex universal\angular-universal-pokedex
> cd dist && node prerender
```

The only way I get the pre-rendering build to complete is by removing the web request. I'm thinking there must still be something running in the background. I tried switching my Observable to a Promise, but that did not change anything. What am I missing?

[You can find my project on GitHub](https://github.com/thijsfranck/angular-universal-pokedex).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: try checking https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE&list=RDQMp7vFjirfv8k&start_radio=1

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but this might help if someone struggles:

> Similarly to the above section on waiting for macrotasks to complete,
> the flip-side is that the platform will not wait for microtasks to
> complete before finishing the render. In Angular Universal, we have
> patched the Angular HTTP client to turn it into a macrotask, to ensure
> that any needed HTTP requests complete for a given render. However,
> this type of patch may not be appropriate for all microtasks, and so
> it is recommended you use your best judgment on how to proceed. You
> can look at the code reference for how Universal wraps a task to turn
> it into a macrotask, or you can simply opt to change the server
> behavior of the given tasks.

Basically if your http requests take too long the prerender hangs and won't finish. Same goes for the websocket connections(firebase uses WS in angular-firebase).
Plus when I had this issue there was no error output in terminal, which made debugging really hard.
I'd sugest following:

- WS connections only on CSR, wrap them asswell in an if statement
- for SSR, or static prerender use rest api endpoints and make sure you don't get any timeout errors.